# Integrating Gyro and Accelerometer Readings to move Robot Straight

Tags: c++, accelerometer, raspberry-pi2, gyroscope, robotics

Now, I am using encoder to move my robot straight, but it is working 75% only. For more accuracy, I have decided to choose gyro and accelerometer reading.

Currently using MPU 6050 accelerometer and gyroscope to get the yaw, pitch, and roll, Acceleration x,y,z of the device, but do not know how to use that information to adjust the speed for straight motion ?

Also I have doubt whether the readings (gyro, accelero) correct or not ?

dmpmpu6050.cpp

```
    float DmpMPU6050_Demo::Loop_Yaw()
{
    if (!dmpReady)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

    if (fifoCount == 1024)
    {
        mpu.resetFIFO();
        printf("FIFO overflow!\n");
    }

    else if (fifoCount >= 42 )
    {
        mpu.getFIFOBytes(fifoBuffer, packetSize);

        #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL
        mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
        mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
        mpu.dmpGetYawPitchRoll(ypr, &q, &gravity);

        return ( ypr[0] * 180/M_PI);
        #endif

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Similar pitch and roll.

```
float DmpMPU6050_Demo::Loop_Accelx()
{
    if (!dmpReady)     
    {
        return 1;
    }
    fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

    if (fifoCount == 1024)
    {
        mpu.resetFIFO();
        printf("FIFO overflow!\n");
    }

    else if (fifoCount >= 42 )
    {
        mpu.getFIFOBytes(fifoBuffer, packetSize);

        #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_REALACCEL
        mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
        mpu.dmpGetAccel(&aa, fifoBuffer);
        mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
        mpu.dmpGetLinearAccel(&aaReal, &aa, &gravity);

        return 1;
        #endif

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Similar Accelerometer y and z

Gyroscopethread.cpp

```
int numbercount=0;
float yawdata;
float accelX;

void GyroScopeThread::run()
{
    gscope = new DmpMPU6050_Demo();
    accelerometer = new DmpMPU6050_Demo();

    gscope->Setup();
    accelerometer->Setup();
    usleep(10000);

    int number = 100;    
    while (true)
    {
        if (this->gyrostop) break;

        yawdata = gscope->Loop_Yaw();

        for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
        {
            float yawdata1 = gscope->Loop_Yaw();

            yawdata = yawdata + yawdata1;

            delay(1);
        }

        yawdata = yawdata/3;

        if(numbercount == number){

        emit Yaw_Data(yawdata);
        cout<<"yaw :"<<yawdata<<endl;

similar calculation for accelero meter 

        numbercount = 0;// count value of data
      }

    }
        numbercount = numbercount+1; // data count increment
 }

    delete gscope;
    delete accelerometer;
}
```

Output :

```
yaw :-14.9574  pitch :-18.3952  roll :-18.3952
Accelx :1.33333  Accely :1  Accelz :1
yaw :-5.5584  pitch :-5.5584  roll :-6.57062
Accelx :0.333333  Accely :0.666667  Accelz :0.666667
yaw :-11.8345  pitch :-10.9161  roll :-10.9161
Accelx :0.666667  Accely :1  Accelz :1
yaw :-4.5936  pitch :-4.5936  roll :-4.5936
Accelx :1.33333  Accely :1.33333  Accelz :1.33333
yaw :-9.574  pitch :-9.574  roll :-9.574
Accelx :0.666667  Accely :1  Accelz :1
yaw :-10.1267  pitch :-10.1267  roll :-10.1267
Accelx :1.33333  Accely :1.33333  Accelz :1.33333
```

At the time of right 90:

```
yaw :-12.2344  pitch :-11.8448  roll :-11.8448
Accelx :1.33333  Accely :1.33333  Accelz :1.33333
yaw :0.726291  pitch :-4.36679  roll :-4.36679
Accelx :1.33333  Accely :1.33333  Accelz :1.33333
yaw :7.62387  pitch :7.62387  roll :7.62387
Accelx :1  Accely :1  Accelz :1
yaw :18.6464  pitch :18.6464  roll :18.6464
Accelx :1.33333  Accely :1.33333  Accelz :1
yaw :-4.06193  pitch :-8.62676  roll :-7.67034
Accelx :1  Accely :1  Accelz :1
yaw :-18.9466  pitch :-17.4917  roll :-12.0176
Accelx :1  Accely :1  Accelz :1
yaw :-4.94824  pitch :-9.12684  roll :-9.12684
Accelx :1  Accely :1  Accelz :1
yaw :-6.94877  pitch :-10.4829  roll :-10.4829
Accelx :1  Accely :1  Accelz :1
yaw :-19.0769  pitch :-17.6077  roll :-12.0728
Accelx :1  Accely :1  Accelz :1
yaw :-3.13396  pitch :-11.7479  roll :-10.2981
Accelx :1  Accely :1  Accelz :1
yaw :12.7717  pitch :1.98726  roll :1.98726
Accelx :0.333336  Accely :0.666668  Accelz :0.666668
yaw :-6.66976  pitch :-6.66976  roll :-6.66976
Accelx :1  Accely :1  Accelz :1
```

Exiting from RightMotion 90

Again straight motion :

```
yaw :-14.1805  pitch :-14.1805  roll :-10.3879
Accelx :0.333508  Accely :0.333508  Accelz :0.666783
```

Comment: This is probably impossible to answer as it's too broad. You're asking this as a a software question, but sensor calibration is also a hardware and signal processing (math) problem. Furthermore, I think you're missing debugging skills - did you start with a_stationary_ sensor first? That should get you a nice zero velocity, zero acceleration reading (ignoring 1g gravity)

Comment: Actually I don't know whether the reading is correct or not, if it is correct means I can proceed further more. Ya I have tried L3G4200D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gyro returns a value indicating the number of degrees positive or negative the robot deviated from its initial heading. As long as the robot continues to go straight, the heading will be zero.
For ex.

```
    class GyroSample : public SampleRobot
{
 RobotDrive myRobot; // robot drive system
 AnalogGyro gyro;
 static const float kP = 0.03;

public:
 GyroSample():
  myRobot(1, 2), // initialize the sensors in initilization list
  gyro(1)
 {
  myRobot.SetExpiration(0.1);
 }

 void Autonomous()
 {
  gyro.Reset();
  while (IsAutonomous())
  {
   float angle = gyro.GetAngle(); // get heading
   myRobot.Drive(-1.0, -angle * kP); // turn to correct heading
   Wait(0.004);
  }
  myRobot.Drive(0.0, 0.0); // stop robot
 }
};
```